# How to get the first column of comm output?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, comm

So I'm trying to get the first column of comm output using `awk`.
I read that Tab was used as a separator for comm so I did:

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $1}' comm-result.txt
```

With comm-result.txt containing the output of:

```
comm -3 file1 file2
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

This commend takes also the space character as a separator and I get weird results when my files contains multiple spaces.

How can i only get the first column from `comm`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> "So I'm trying to get the first column of comm output"

The first column of the "`comm file1 file2`" output contains lines unique to the `file1`. You can skip the post-processing by simply calling `comm` with `-2` (suppress lines unique to `file2`) and `-3` (suppress lines that appear in both files).

```
comm -2 -3 file1 file2   # will show only lines unique to file1
```

---

However, if you have no choice but to process a pre-run output of `comm` then as [Carl mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8299592/115845), `cut` would be an option:

```
cut -f1 comm-results.txt
```

However, this result in empty lines for cases where column 1 is empty. To deal with this, perhaps `awk` may be more suitable:

```
awk -F"\t" '{if ($1) print $1}' comm-results.txt
     ----    ----------------
      |                     |
   Use tab as delimiter     |
                            +-- only print if not empty
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i wasn't aware of the -1 and -2 options, i thought i had to process the result.

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't aware of it either, until I looked up the man page.

Answer (score 8):

[`cut(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/) is probably a better choice than `awk` for this problem.

Comment: Ah... I see it now. I missed it as I was scanning through the answers.

Comment: @CarlNorum And that means this _answer_ should be a comment on the accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `comm` with `-2` and `-3` (as [already explained above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8299660/55075)), or use `comm` with `grep` like:

```
grep -o '^\S\+' <(comm file1 file2)
```

so the output won't contain any trailing spaces. This is useful for non-`comm` commands.

Comment: Works super good on ps output with just a little tweak! `ps -A | grep node | grep -o '^\s*\S\+'`