# Get first word of every line with AWK or SED?

Tags: awk, sed, split

I have a text file like this:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc
dddd eeee ffff
gggg hhhh iiii
...
..
.
```

How can I create a text file only with first column of every lines with `awk` or `sed` like this?

```
aaaa
dddd
gggg
...
..
.
```

I have seen similar topics but I could not resolve my problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing only the first field in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024561/printing-only-the-first-field-in-a-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first column of every line from a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668621/how-to-get-the-first-column-of-every-line-from-a-csv-file) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959746/extracting-columns-space-or-tab-delimited-from-text-file-in-linux or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299553/how-to-get-the-first-column-of-comm-output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your input is

```
aaaa bbbb cccc
dddd eeee ffff
gggg hhhh iiii
```

and what you want is:

```
aaaa
dddd
gggg
```

then you can use any of:

```
awk NF=1       input.file
sed 's/ .*//'  input.file
cut -d' ' -f1  input.file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`: By setting number of fields to 1:

```
awk '{NF=1}1' inputfile
```

Using `grep` and look arounds:

```
grep -oP '^.[^ ]+' inputfile
```

Using `sed` backrefrencing:

```
sed -r 's/(^.[^ ]+).*/\1/' inputfile
```

Comment: Why the "." at the start of the sed and grep patterns?

Comment: @mischa , here dot means any character so ^. Means line start followed by any character.

Comment: Yes, I know "what" it means; I was puzzled "why" you had it.
For the example input, it is redundant. For input that permits a one-character first field, it fails.I'm sure you had a a reason ... but what?